# Why doesn't struct declaration compile in Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, c, struct, android-ndk

How can a struct be compiled with Android NDK?

The following declaration (works fine with g++)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

//header construction here...
    private:
      struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
```

gives the error:

```
error: field 'serv_addr' has incomplete type
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
                   ^
```

Comment: Doesn't need all those nowadays fancy [tag:android] tags. It's pretty common, see @David's answer! Also can be found at `<arpa/inet.h>`.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer - your decision to remove the C tag presumably implies that you are confident enough of what the issue is to back up your claim that it is unique to C++ and not shared with C, so please provide your answer.  Otherwise, the edit should be reverted, as the only current answer is in fact something that applies to C every bit as much as C++.

Comment: The question and answer do, indeed, apply equally to C and C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `#include <netinet/in.h>`

Comment: You might also mention [<arpa/inet.h>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/arpainet.h.html) as I suggested in my comment. I really don't see any _android_ specific here.

Comment: why does it compile with another compiler then?

Comment: I get the same error with both gcc and g++ (after removing the private and the C++ headers so that it's C)

Comment: Perhaps if you include more of your code fragment that might give some hints, but my best guess would be that when you copied the code you didn't copy all the headers?

Comment: ok using the two mentioned includes made it compile properly. I don't know why it compiled without the includes before (its not a copy/paste mistake). Thanks anyway